# Dynamically generating select tags with dynamic options and add generate another select tag when an option is selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

As the title of the question. This is what I want to achieve. I have a webpage when the web page loads it loads options (from db) to the static select tag. So there's only 1 static select tag. And when the user select an option from that 1st tag another select tag with the same options should be generated below the 1st tag and also data table containing data according to selected option should be appear in a table. And when the user select an option from the newly generated select tag then another tag with the same options should be generated below the select tag and same with the data table. Like this it goes on.

**I'm using laravel as backend. And did all the data retrieving via ajax get.**

So far I was able to get the options from the db and dynamically add the options to select tags also get the data table according to selected option in the static tag.

But it didn't generate another tag after selecting an option from the 2nd select tag.

This is the static select tag code

```
<div class="row" id="routeDetailsRow">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-bordered">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="routeCode" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Date</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="date" name="date" id="date" class="col-sm-8 form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="routeCode" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Route Code</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <select id="selectRoute" class="form-control">

                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="panel panel-bordered">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id="routePlanTablediv">
                        <div id="noResultsDiv"><h4 id="noResultDivText"></h4></div>
                        <div class="lds-ellipsis"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover no-display" id="routePlanTable">
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th>Invoice No</th>
                                <th>Route Code</th>
                                <th>Customer Code</th>
                                <th>Routeplan Code</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="routePlanTableBody">
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm passing the static select tag's id to load the options to the tag like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    getUserData('selectRoute'); //this is the function and works as expected

    $("#enterVehicleNo").on("keydown", function(event) {
        $("#selectRoute").removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```

This is how I get the data table with the static select tag and generate new select tag.

```
$(document).on('change', '#selectRoute', function() {
    var selector_id = '#selectRoute';
    var table_id = '#routePlanTable';
    getSelectedRouteDetails(selector_id, table_id); //data table function
    addRows(); //add new select tag function
});
```

getSelectedRouteDetails() function

```
function getSelectedRouteDetails(selector_id, table_id) {
    var selectedRC = document.getElementById(selector_id).value;
    var result = $('#' +selector_id).val().split('|');
    $('#routeplanno').text(result[1]);
    console.log(selectedRC);
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('.lds-ellipsis').hide();
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: 'retreiveRouteData',
        data: {
            RouteCode: result[0]
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'get',
        success: function(result) {
            if (result) {
                $(table_id).removeClass('no-display');
                $(table_id + ' tbody').html(result);
                $('#noResultDivText').hide();
            } else {
                $(table_id).addClass('no-display');
                $('#noResultDivText').text('No results were found !');
            }
        }
    });

}
```

**I'm using mustache.js to generate a new select tag** and the template is same as the static select tag with dynamic ids followed by count (selectRoute_1)

addRows() function

```
var template = $("#form_rows_tpl").html(),
$target = $("#generate_new_route"),
$btnRemove = $("button.remove"),
$msg = $('.msg'),
max = 10,
count = 1,
inputRow = [];

$btnRemove.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    removeRows();
});

var sId,tableID;
function addRows() {
    if (count <= max) {
        inputRow = {
            count: count
        }
        tableID = 'routePlanTable_1'; //hardcoded the table id and select tag id for testing purpose
        sId = 'selectRoute_1';

        var html = Mustache.to_html(template, inputRow);
        $target.append(html);
        count++;

        var routecode_selector = document.getElementsByClassName('route-code-selector');
        console.log(routecode_selector.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < routecode_selector.length; i++) {
            var select_id = routecode_selector[i].getAttribute('id');
            $('#'+select_id).removeAttr('disabled');
            newRoute(select_id,tableID);
        }
    } else {
        $msg.text('too many fields!');
    }
}

function removeRows() {
    $target.find('.row').last().remove();
    $msg.text('');
    if (count <= 1) {
        count = 1;
    } else {
        count--;
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is how to get the dynamically generated select tags ids' and pass them to addRows() function. And I know this is kind of a messy code and if some of you have any suggestions and if there are other better ways to achieve this please comment them below.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying I was able to solved my issue with adding a button to generate a new select tag instead of generating a select tag after user select an option. And functions should be called in right time and in right functions.